# Is Qt QSharedMemory supported on Android?

Tags: android, qt, shared-memory

I am trying to use QSharedMemory. It works fine under Windows, not in Android. The very first `create` call fails. It is not linked to the key, as I have used different values.

My `main.cpp` is as follows:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QSharedMemory>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
  if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    return -1;

  QSharedMemory _sharedMemory("QtMemTest", nullptr);
  if (!_sharedMemory.create(sizeof(int), QSharedMemory::ReadWrite))
    qDebug() << "Failed " << _sharedMemory.errorString();
  else
    qDebug() << "Size " << QString::number(_sharedMemory.size());

  return app.exec();
}
```

On Windows, I get:

> Size "4096"

On Android:

> main.cpp:17 (int main(int, char**)): Failed "QSharedMemory::create:
>   unable to lock"

This is with a single process, just trying to create the shared memory block.

This really looks like a basic problem... Do I need a specific Android permission? Is this available in Android?

I am using Qt Creator 4.6.2, am targeting gcc 4.9, Qt 5.9.6 for Android armv7.
I have tried on Android devices running 6.0 and 8.0.

**Edit**

Tried this with Qt 5.11.1, the problem is still the same.

Also, while running this, I get a series of warnings on the application output console:

> W libsharedExample.so: (null):0 ((null)): Unimplemented code.

Commenting out the `create` call removes 6 such warnings. How to figure out what features are implemented in a given Qt release? If this is not implemented for Android, how is an app supposed to communicate with its service (which is a different process)?

Comment: Had a couple of answers here:
[link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/92475/is-qsharedmemory-supported-on-android/6)
From what I understand, QSharedMemory relies on QSystemSemaphore. Testing those on Android sends back the same type of errors.

Comment: So it looks like neither of these features are implemented.

It would still be good if all that was indicated in the Qt class specs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this class is not implemented on Android. The `unimplemented code` warning is genuine.

A reliable way to move data between processes on Android seems to be with QtRemoteObject.